# show/hide if in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I wrote a script that hide/show me sidenav. My problem is that I would like to have all in one function. First, whether that examined the sidenav is hidden or not. If hidden, by clicking showed sidenav and if sidenav visible, click to hide sidenav.
My code:

```
function showSideNav () {
    var sideNav = document.getElementById("slide-out");

    sideNav.style.cssText = "transform: translateX(0); -webkit-transition: 0.5s;";
}

function closeSideNav () {
    var sideNav = document.getElementById("slide-out");

    sideNav.style.cssText = "transform: translateX(-100%); -webkit-transition: 0.5s;";
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to manage if you put the CSS in a style sheet with a class, and then in JS test whether the element already has that class and add or remove as required to toggle.

Comment: toggle a class, set the styles in a stylesheet. `elementNodeReference.classList.toggle("yourClass");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a `boolean` variable holding information if the `sidenav` is visible or not and according to it's value - show it or hide.

```js
var sideNav = document.getElementById("slide-out"),
    sideNavVisible = true;

function toggleSideNav() {
  if (sideNavVisible) {
    sideNav.style.cssText = "transform: translateX(-100%); -webkit-transition: 0.5s;";
  } else {
    sideNav.style.cssText = "transform: translateX(0); -webkit-transition: 0.5s;";
  }
  sideNavVisible = !sideNavVisible;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#slide-out {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw
}

.x {
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id='slide-out'></div>
<button onclick="toggleSideNav()" class='x'>Toggle sidenav</button>
<div class='container' onclick='sideNavVisible = true;toggleSideNav()'></div>
```

Comment: This solves my problem! Thanks! One more question, if there is a possibility that if the burial of clicks outside the div that he hide?

Comment: @paciek You want to hide the div when clicked outside?

Comment: Yes, when i click outside div is hide.

Comment: @paciek It would be difficult in pure js, it can be easily done with jQuery.

Comment: I can use only pure JS.

Comment: @paciek I will try to provide you solution when im back from my work.

Comment: @paciek Assuming that your sidenav will be positioned absolutely, this solution may be fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to manage if you put the CSS in a style sheet with classes, and then in JS toggle those classes:

```js
function toggleSideNav () {
    var sideNav = document.getElementById("slide-out");
    sideNav.classList.toggle("hidden");
    sideNav.classList.toggle("visible");
}

// button for demo purposes:
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", toggleSideNav);
```

```css
.visible { transform: translateX(0); -webkit-transition: 0.5s; }
.hidden { transform: translateX(-100%); -webkit-transition: 0.5s; }
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<div id="slide-out" class="visible">This is my test sliding div.</div>
```